# Positioning MPMoviePlayerController view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got a little problem when trying to position the view of a MPMoviePlayerController. Here is my code so far.

```
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:URL]];
    moviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake((CGFloat)vidX, (CGFloat)vidY, (CGFloat)vidWidth, (CGFloat)vidHeight)];

    //Find ApplicationWindow 
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIWindow * win= [delegate window];
    [win addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
```

The code works fine and the movie is shown. However the positioning is making me crazy.  When I change the width or the height of the view I expect the view to stay at the exact x and y position and only width and height should change. But this is not the case. When I change vidWidth or vidHeight and leave vidX and vidY untouched the origin of the view jumps to another point, which makes it extremely hard to position the video view.
Any help will be appreciated.

Best Regards,

Rambazamba

Comment: Have you tried just setting the center where you want?

Comment: Yeah but it dit not work either :-C Thx